# Is the homepage implied in [BreadcrumbList JSON LD + Schema.org]?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Looking at the examples Google provides [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb), the first breadcrumb seems to be already 1 level deep.

Am I correct to assume that the homepage is then determined to be the root domain? What if it's a subdomain?

The example code from the link above, quoted:

```
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "name": "Books",
    "item": "https://example.com/books"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Authors",
    "item": "https://example.com/books/authors"
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "name": "Ann Leckie",
    "item": "https://example.com/books/authors/annleckie"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**under schema.org docs:**

> beginning with '1' for the first item in the list

https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList

**No zero value** (No way to declare "the zero item in the list").

This markup is ok/valid (In my list `home` = first item in the list):

`home > blog`

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/">
    <span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/blog/">
    <span itemprop="name">blog</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

[image]
**SUM:** Schema.org give semantic meaning for you content. Position 1 could be root-domain or sub-domain.

### Rich Snippet:

**Most of the times google omits "homepage" (name) from the snippet (Moz "real source code" example):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is to check how Google displays your page in the search results. The breadcrumb markup are suggestions for the way the url part of the search result is displayed.

I've seen markup including "home" page items causing poor looking results by showing "home" in the snippet.

While other times Google has understood that it should be ignored.

Safest bet, don't include the root. You also don't need to include the current page.